# How can I create a reusable get element function using typescript generics?

Tags: typescript, dom, typescript-generics

I'm trying to merge the selectElement and getElement functions into a reusable typescript generic function where I can use select the element(s) and still be able to call them as the following...

> `const btnArray = getElementTS<HTMLButtonElement>('.btn', '.container', true)`

> or `const singleBtn = getElementTS<HTMLButtonElement>('.btn', '.container')`

P.S. Forgive any errors I might have made. **I'm just a newbie.**

```
   // this function returns a single element
   const selectElement = (selector, scope) => {
      return (scope || document).querySelector(selector);
   };
    
   // this function returns either a single element or an element array
   function getElement(selector, isList) {
       let element = isList
       ? [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]
       : document.querySelector(selector);

  if ((!isList && element) || (isList && !element.length < 1)) return element;
  throw new Error(`Please double check your selector : ${selector}`);
}

interface Length {
  length: number;
}

// merging the two functions with a typescript version
function getElementTS<E extends Length & HTMLElement & string>(
  selector: string,
  scope: E,
  isList: boolean
) {
  let element = isList
    ? ([...(scope || document).querySelectorAll(selector)] as E[])
    : ((scope || document).querySelector(selector) as E);

  if ((!isList && el) || (isList && !element.length < 1)) return el;
  throw new Error(`Please double check your selector : ${selector}`);
}

console.log(getElementTS('.btn', '.main' ,true));
```

Comment: There are several errors in your code: `getElement` only accepts two arguments but at the top of your question you are supplying with three arguments in some cases, and their types are not compatible. Also, the way you use `scope` is incorrect, since you seem to be providing a CSs selector string to `scope`, but is using it in as `scope.querySelectorAll(selector)` if it is truthy. That will throw errors since `String` does not have the method `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @Terry ok, so how do I fix it, since i can't pass the scope arg in the function as a string? and I meant getElementTS. will fix that

Comment: Before I post my answer, just want to clarify something: your “btn” selector will select the `<btn>` element: I am assuming you’re referring to either `.btn` or `button`?

Comment: @Terry; Thanks. You are a godsend. I've also fixed the issue with my selector args for those who may view this later.  I only started typescript last month, so was using this as a fun practice exercise. I'd even forgotten about function overloads. Typescript has got me hooked with its expressive power making me wonder why I didn't learn it sooner. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be explicit about what is returned based on the value of `isList`, I would suggest rewriting the logic in your function as such:

```
const parsedSelector = scope ? `${scope} ${selector}` : selector;
try {
    if (isList) {
        const element = [...document.querySelectorAll(parsedSelector)] as T[];
        if (element.length < 1) throw Error;
        return element;
    } else {
        const element = document.querySelector(parsedSelector) as T;
        if (!element) throw Error;
        return element;
    }
} catch(e) {
     throw new Error(`Please double check your selector : ${selector}`);
}
```

By doing this, you won't run into issues where TypeScript fails to narrow the type for `element` in this potentially problematic line:

```
if ((!isList && el) || (isList && !element.length < 1)) return el;
```

Moreover, it is necessary to create a `parsedSelector` to ensure that the `scope` and `selector` variables are properly concatenated. Using `scope.querySelectorAll()` in your original code will throw an error because `scope` is a string and not an `Element`.

Then, it is just a matter of adding function overloads to ensure proper correspondence between the provided arguments and the expected return type:

```
function getElementTS<T extends Element>(selector: string, scope: string): T
function getElementTS<T extends Element>(selector: string, scope: string, isList: true): T[]
function getElementTS<T extends Element>(selector: string, scope: string, isList: false): T
function getElementTS<T extends Element>(
    selector: string,
    scope: string,
    isList?: boolean
): T | T[] {
    // Function logic here
}
```

[See example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQKIBtUFtVhQAqAygDxGKoAeUBAJgM6LZ4FQB8AFI6jtHABOALkSMogmGGQAaMRDgAHVKPGTpASlFEAUKEiwEKdK3yFSFKrQbNT7br35QhqiVNnylKsW%20lyYjAAyAVCiEiCoWohEANoAunrg0PBIaJg4ZsTklDR0YEwsGfY8fKgCIj7qHowKyq5V-kEhosAAhli8Ubr6yUZpdubZVnkFA5xcOohTYqXl9e4yk9M1XvN%20S1MBweIA-KIARnBwOK1gOl2IAD7R8YgA3huICmDiiIqtgrz0JLPOgogAXk8ykQO0QAAMACR3FbKAC%20iGhjjKfzh4MQql%20QgA3I8JABPe6PaaIGDARBcLYhDREkl06bPV6lTKAxAxAB0nPocAgIEy7IAjhFBPifk4hABBLBYLjvT6ob5YwQaOKIVrMWJxXH0%20lkinM9jsnDSKAAC0QZEQAEYaWbBHAAO4sQT2wTanUkwToECCJAGwju%20kIvi8WkehkIJlFQis7m8-lC1AisUooSyj5fFPlGnq6KB8N6rgAQn9UFtpvtTowLpxxJ1XqgPr90ag%20ZJcMeCIgrSgEFNXEiYZ1dsdiDAqCrNcEXHBAAUTqHuSB9jgnqaygBrRD4uA%20mbi-6iJFKtEafMdjs6RlQRD7KBgCUu1qEoH9FsWAASRAAsoEAEIgFAzhgGM3AAOR3mAYFyGB7LPFArRSEm0GIOEkTYiSAD0mGIAASt6vrMOCX6-gBQEIGM8TglekY3ow7g4H%2095Wqyb5sIMZAkf%20gHAaBXAQfeKGwfBiHjoIKFtB06GINheEES8EJcWRvEttR15iAxqBMWAABMrEmO%205BKTxFEtuBkFCXBCAIUh4lnh6sn4Y2hGKT%203HkSBqlAA).

Answer (score 0):

This is a revised solution from the answer to my earlier question.
The purpose of this function is to get an element or elements from the DOM and throw a useful exception if they are not found

```
function getElement<T extends Element>(
  selector: string,
  scope: ParentNode | Document
): T;
function getElement<T extends Element>(
  selector: string,
  scope: ParentNode | Document,
  isElementArray: true
): T[];
function getElement<T extends Element>(
  selector: string,
  scope: ParentNode | Document,
  isElementArray: false
): T;
function getElement<T extends Element>(
  selector: string,
  scope: ParentNode | Document,
  isElementArray?: boolean
): T | T[] {
  try {
    if (isElementArray) {
      const element = [...scope.querySelectorAll(selector)] as T[];
      if (element.length < 1) throw Error;
      return element;
    } else {
      const element = scope.querySelector(selector) as T;
      if (!element) throw Error;
      return element;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(
      `There is an error. Please check if your selector: ${selector} is correct`
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
/* returns HTMLButtonElement */
const tabList = getElement<HTMLDivElement>('.tab-list', document, false)
const tabButton = getElement<HTMLButtonElement>('.tabBtn', tabList')
const navBtn = getElement('.btn--mobile-toggle', document) as HTMLButtonElement

/* returns HTMLButtonElement[] i.e Array<HTMLButtonElement>*/
const tabButtons = getElement<HTMLButtonElement>('.tabBtn', tabList, true)
const logos = getElement('.logo', document, true) as HTMLImageElement[]
```

[See example on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQKIBtUFtVhQA8AKoqgB5QEAmAzotngVAHwAUAUIonajtDgAnAFy8oQmGGQAabrwhwADqjEAFAIZCWAOTg1UiAD6IAInAgh8hTgEoxJANydQkWAhTom14mUrUwekYcHw55PgEoYTE6CSlZcMUVdS1dfUMTc0sfOR4YOm8WAEEhIQ0ATzEJEFQ7BwBtAF1nV2h4JDRMEJZScipaBkLCMJ4I1EFRcUlpXIVlVURNbUI9A2MzCysWWfyhqBKyysRgDSw%20OsQnF3A2j0693v8B4OZhrlH%20cajJ2OmE0aSCyWaTWmU2OXku26hAOFQA-GIAEZwOA4DRgC5kEwkJqIADe8gk5Xx8jywEQ7Chr32pQqthJPEZiEUYFi5GhUEQAF5EPUAHQCuiAvkARxqQnKAGVPhMilgsOwxhNbI1EBoGDjmqTGTByexPj4%20ThpFAABaIIiIACM9LNQjgAHdGKVhM4mTxtFAQEIkAaWG7GQBfdl8Bnullsv2EblzFSi8VSmXfRVJ4T09WXANM3UUgCEUagttN9qdGBdQizjM93t9HMrgfkwYgGigEHN%20vpBKZdsdiDAqFL5fe7oABiRTahtIh8mrfeW%20Ys0aG2%20MANbT8nlODe3ipyYAEjxSu%20wZnilKXxH2tsAYbDYA9PeAKp0DRoEScTj3gBUiGrPoYAAJEgAFkABkACEQCgKIwD2RBv3vTgI05KANERMD8k5Hl7g5IhgPA0wYAANz2DgAHI%20TQxEAFosCw8iZEQGhwW2Y5Tj4WxkIQNlqKgmCPBwrw8IIyDoNgsj2EovioDARjEGozDYi4lC%20w0YiINkmNcOpKS%20URWSaJo3A4ERGAcBoqJkGQHB5JY7IWHTIDQLEgS4I5T8fz-dAa2c8D%20IkjlcRgPlDFhcp8JcgKEDIxDuNZVD0Oi1ltOE6lIv88SYo5CiqKS2T5MUrCmOqVAVJ4zksDgZA4AYISul0yiqpquzWMIEqhBqJzEFEgBJXA31QPYmiAA)